# When to use Postgresql array data type

Tags: postgresql

I see that PostgreSQL has an array data type. What is it used for? When is the best situation to use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the proper use-cases for the PostgreSQL Array Datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843912/what-are-the-proper-use-cases-for-the-postgresql-array-datatype)

Answer (score 2):

Defining a column as an array usually means that you have a denormalized model because the content of that array could also be stored as a 1:n relationship.

But the sometimes it makes sense to do so especially if you always treat the "list" as "one thing". It's hard to give concrete examples though. If you can't think of anything, you probably don't need it.